# Why won't anything happen when I change margin values?

Tags: html, css

I'm putting a floating picture on my friends blog real quick, but changing the margin values doesn't do anything.

```
#pic{ 
z-index:9999999999999999; 
position:fixed; 
width:200px; 
background-color: transparent;}
```

And the structure:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:0px;" id="pic" ><img src="{image:Sidepicture}" style="width:200px;"</a></div>
```

When I change the margin values, the picture stays at the top left hand corner no matter what I do.

Comment: You're HTML is wrong for a start.  You don't close your `<img` tag and you don't open your `</a>` tag.  But that aside, the margin works for me: http://jsbin.com/AnUVisAV/1/edit

Comment: Oops, wrong bin. http://jsbin.com/AnUVisAV/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is likely position: fixed;

```
#pic{ 
z-index:9999999999999999; 
position:fixed; 
width:200px; 
background-color: transparent;}
```

Is this all the code there is for pic? It seems that #pic is stuck to top: 0, left: 0

Try just removing the position: fixed line entirely and see what happens

If doesn't work out, also try adding position:relative;

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work. I'm not sure if the only possible problems are in this code so I'll link a pastebay

Answer (score 0):

Because you should be putting the margin on the `<img />`, not on the `<div>` surrounding the image (`#pic`).

```
#pic img { margin: 20px; }
```

... will do what you want it to.

Comment: Hmm still hasn't worked. My comment on the other answer has the link for the whole code.

Comment: Rather than the whole code like that, do you have a site we can see your problem at? And when you say "change the margin values", are you talking about the inline style on the `<div>` where it currently says `margin-bottom:0px;`? What do you want it to be?

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't realize I had a </a>

Answer (score 0):

The very least you should have done is validate that your HTML and CSS are actually valid. There are many errors in the code and style that you supplied. Unclosed Tags, Closed tags, Unmatched elements, styles without contents, invalid styles, Incorrect declarations and so on.

Its also a bit of a jumbled mess, with interwoven styles and script and parts of reset scripts towards the end, all sprinkled through with optional block and cycle contents, making helping you very difficult. Keeping your style separate from your code and grouping it into one block would help you narrow it down a bit as right now styles are all over the file, making it easy for anyone to miss the offending line.

I can only suggest that one of the later styles in your CSS after the style for img you are trying to apply. (somewhere after line 152) is overriding the margin that you are setting at 152. You can use the developer tools built into the browser and look at which styles are being applied to your element and which line in the file they come from. If your pix style is not applied then you will at least have an idea what other styles are and this will allow you to narrow down your investigation.

another way to find the offending line would be to to comment out the styles after line 152 and then comment them back in a few at a time, until you find the class causing the issue.

The quick and dirty fix is of course to put !important after your margin

You can also run your page through the [CSS Validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and [HTML validation](http://validator.w3.org/) to help you find any of the errors that may also be having an effect.